# How to check class of parent element by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my second script in jquery. What I want to do:

```
<span class="">
    <input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
</span>
```

This is default. When user click on this input field, the system add class checked to span. So the results is:

```
<span class="checked">
    <input name="personalData1" id="personalData1" value="0" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
</span>
```

I want to change value of this input. If it's checked than value is 1 in other way it will be 0. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#personalData1").change(function () {
        $('#opc_payment_methods-content').removeClass('hide');

        if ($('#personalData1 > span').hasClass('checked')) {
            window.alert('ok');
        }
    });
});
```

Something is wrong with this if statement, I can not get in and display alert. Thanks for any help.

Kind regards

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem If you want to know whether the checkbox is checked or not, ask the checkbox, not the parent.

Comment: I need to ask the parent in this example. I mean in Prestashop 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `parent`method, for more information [Jquery .parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

So in your function it will be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#personalData1").change(function () {
        $('#opc_payment_methods-content').removeClass('hide');

        if ($('#personalData1').parent().hasClass('checked') == false) {
            window.alert('ok');
            $('#personalData1').parent().addClass('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Glad to hear it =) If the solution helps you could you note it as correct answer ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing the checkbox `$('#personalData1 > span')` as the parent. instead do this:

```
 if ($('#personalData1').parent().hasClass('checked')) {
     window.alert('ok');
  }
```